# How To Read Vimeo RSS Feed Using PHP

Tags: php, curl, vimeo, vimeo-api

I want to read the rss feed for my videos from Vimeo using a PHP script so I can update a database table with video data, however even though I can read the feed in my browser, Vimeo returns a 500 error.

I looked at their API documentation which is about as clear as mud and wants me to create an API. I don't want an API for visitors to use, I just want to read a feed (which would normally be simple using curl.

I haven't found any help at all from their documentation, hopefully someone could make it a bit clearer for me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this:-

http://simplepie.org/

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve this. Feeling rather dumb now, the content of the curled rss feed from Vimeo did not display on the screen when echoed because of some of the content. It was however returned. I needed to view the screen source to see the content.